# got 500 error using alt=media while success using 'downloadUrl' field in file resource

Tags: download, google-api, google-drive-api

Recently, one of our client reports that he cannot backup files in his Team Drive using our app. We will be thankful if someone can help us figure out why.

We use `alt=media` method to download file. That is, `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?alt=media`. [Reference link here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads). It works perfectly for most of the files on client side.

However, if we download *some of files* using this method, we got the following response from Google:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

These files are in Team Drive and with various extensions (not online doc). For example, `.xlsx`, `.pdf`, `.jpg`, etc. We re-tried few days and **ALWAYS** got this response message (500 with `null` message). We cannot get this working even if we append `&supportsTeamDrives=true` at the end of the URL.

By checking with GET file API, this file DOES exist on Google Drive. Even more surprisingly, we CAN DOWNLOAD this file using the URL provided in `downloadUrl` field from file resource! How could this happen?

We cannot find more information from Google's API document about this phenomenon. Please help us if someone knows why.

Thank you!

**UPDATED:**

We got the latest information from our client. It seems that these files are under some folders which are **migrated** from My Drive to Team Drive. Also, the creation time of these folders are ranging from 2014 to 2016, which are before the official Team Drive early adoption program.

We don't know if these facts are related to the download problem or not, since not all files under these folders are problematic. Only some of these files cannot download through `alt=media` method.

Comment: Can you show us your current script? To show your script will be helpful to think the solutions.

Comment: no idea if you're using apps script, java , javascript, python, php, .NET lol

Comment: We use curl to send API request. In this case, the curl command looks like this: `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]" "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?alt=media"`.

Comment: havent used that before..are you s ill using drive api or just copied the URL from drive API and pasted it in your own implementation?

Comment: Actually, we use `libcurl` in C code, and send API request using curl's interface. In this case, we use `curl_easy_setopt` to setup headers, method, URL, ..., etc, and use `curl_easy_perform` to send API request.